# swift decode json data

Tags: ios, swift

I have following json data returns form php.

```
{"Response":"OK","Data":[{"id":"1","organization_name":"Organization","description":"Description","address":"Address1, Ny, USA"}]}
```

In need to decode it using swift

Below is my code.

```
struct OrgData: Decodable {
    let data: [Data]
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "Data"
    }
}

struct Data: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let address: String
    let description: String
    let organization_name: String
    
}
```

and I am decoding it using

```
  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }

     guard let dataObj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(OrgData.self, from: data) else {
             print("Error: Couldn't decode data ")
              return
     }

   ..................
```

But no data I am getting in `dataObj`.

I am referring this article

https://roadfiresoftware.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-4/

Comment: `try?` is equal to "If there is an error, I don't want to hear about it. Could it have more info on why it failed? Yes, but I don't care. Instead, do a property `do/try/catch`! Are you getting `print("Error: Couldn't decode data ")` output? If not, where `dataObj` is nil?

Comment: No I am not getting Error: Couldn't decode data, Can debug to below and see no data on `dataObj`

Comment: Show where you see that `dataObj` has "no data". It's unclear if that's an async issue. Do you print it? Where?

Comment: You are right, I think async issue, previously I watched the value using break point and debug. Now I print and can see the result

Comment: Unrelated but basically never name a custom object `Data`. It could interfere with the Foundation struct `Data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues with how your structs were configured:

- There is no field for the "Response" value
- Data is an array, not a `String`

The following appears to properly output the json you give:

```
import Foundation

let json =
"""
    {"Response":"OK","Data":[{"id":"1","organization_name":"Organization","description":"Description","address":"Address1, Ny, USA"}]}
"""

// MARK: - OrgData
struct OrgData: Codable {
    let response: String
    let data: [Datum]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case response = "Response"
        case data = "Data"
    }
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    let id, organizationName, datumDescription, address: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case organizationName = "organization_name"
        case datumDescription = "description"
        case address
    }
}

guard let data = json.data(using: .utf8) else {
    return
}

do {
    let dataObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(OrgData.self,
                                           from: data)
    print(dataObj)
    // Optional(__lldb_expr_1.OrgData(response: "OK", data: [__lldb_expr_1.Datum(id: "1", organizationName: "Organization", datumDescription: "Description", address: "Address1, Ny, USA")]))

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in a helper class

```
func decodedObject<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, dictionaryData: JSONDictionary) throws -> T? {
    guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionaryData,
                                                     options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) else {
        return nil
    }

    let decodedData = try self.decode(type, from: jsonData)
    return decodedData
}
```

Now call it like follows:

```
guard let dataObj = try? JSONDecoder().decodedObject(OrgData.self, dictionaryData: data) else {
         print("Error: Couldn't decode data ")
          return
 }
```